# Paginate all JPA queries

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am creating a web service and I wondered if there was a solution to paginate all queries.
Currently I am creating overloaded methods such as `findAll(int offset, int limit)` etc. But I wondered if there was another solution to this which doesn't create that much duplication of logic in the finders. I want to this at database level. Or is the solution that I came up with an OK approach?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How could you get a specific page without passing the specific page you want as argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may want to use method overloading to avoid duplication of logic, if duplication is the primary concern.

1. Change all your existing `findAll` methods to support pagination as you have mentioned:

   ```
   findAll(int offset, int limit)
   ```
2. Then create overloaded `findAll()` method and internally call the `findAll` methods created in step 1 with default values e.g. below:

   ```
   findAll(){
     //set appropriate defaults, Integer.MAX_VALUE is just an example 
     findAll(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   }
   ```